# Install a different version of chaincode (Hyperledger fabic)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I just start learning and follow the BYFN tutorial on the [official website](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html).

I'm really not sure does the Hyperledger fabric support to install a different version of chaincode in some peers

I'm trying to install my chaincode named **mycc-1.0.1 on peer0Org1 and peer1Org1** and **mycc-1.0.0 on peer0Org2 and peer1Org2**

Then when I trying to query or invoke some data via command (`peer chaincode invoke` / `peer chaincode query`) on peer0Org2 or peer1Org2 (mycc-1.0.0) I got this error

```
Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"cannot retrieve package for chaincode mycc/1.0.1, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/mycc.1.0.1: no such file or directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you are running Fabric 1.4.x)

You `install` on to a peer - a quick task that copies files.

You `instantiate` on a channel - and a channel has *one current version*.  The instantiate takes longer as a chaincode image is built and a container started.  This means that you *cannot* have different versions on different peers.

(If you want to run 2 different versions in the same channel you would have to use different names.)

In test networks with default policies in place, the instantiate typically builds and starts a chaincode container on 1 peer, and when a transaction is invoked on a different peer there is a delay whilst the chaincode container for that peer is built/started.

In you case it looks like v101 has been instantiated on the channel, and the peers for Org 2 try to build/start v101 but they can't find the code because you have not installed it.  If you install v101 to the peers for Org 2, then they should build the new containers and you should get results back from invoke.

Comment: So can I use both of these versions together on the same channel?

Comment: If I change the name of chaincode I need to instantiate it again, but I want to change only the version of my chaincode. Can it be possible?

Comment: You would need to install the new version to all the peers, then run `peer chaincode upgrade` just once for the channel.  (This will create a new chaincode container for each peer when it needs it.)